# Trying to create a published browser based npm package, but import isn't working

Tags: javascript, html, npm, webpack

I am using webpack to create and bundle up a package. I've then published it to NPM. Then in a test environment I install the package but using import/export doesn't work:
This is the webpack file for the package I uploaded.

```
/* webpack.config.js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.js',
  target: 'web',
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        library: 'myWebpackPackage',
        libraryTarget: 'umd',
    },
};
```

The simple function I created in the index.js:

```
export function add(a, b) {
return a + b;
}
```

The package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "my-first-npm-package-twelve",
  "version": "1.0.6",
  "description": "",
  "main": "./dist/bundle.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "Me",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "cli": "^1.0.1",
    "webpack": "^5.90.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4"
  }
}
```

I successfuly publish to the NPM repository.
However when I come to importing it into my test environment it only works if I specifically label the path:
index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <script type="module" src="./node_modules/my-first-npm-package-twelve/dist/bundle.js"></script>
  <script  type="module" src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Index.js:

```
console.log(myWebpackPackage.add(5,6));
```

Which prints the answer 11 in the browser javascript console:
[image]

Please let me know what I am doing wrong, I've been struggling with this for the passed week.

I expected that by placing an import statement in the index.js that I could call the function from. the downloaded package.

Comment: What happens when you add the import to the `index.js`? How do you build your page?

Comment: @korad, which index.js? the one in the packaged library or the test environment. I am using webpack to build the page.

Comment: The testing environment